# Eclipse : Welcome page not getting displayed

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, plugins

I am working on an application which is built on top of **Eclipse**. Though everything is working fine on windows, Sles 32 and 64 bit, but on SLED 64 bit the Welcome page is not getting Displayed. When you try to open the welcome page it throws an **MalformedUrl** exception with 
**"Could not load Swt Style: content/shared.css"** as error message.

When i checked on net, i discovered that several people seems to have encountered this problem but i couldn't find a solution. Please help me out guys.

Comment: The welcome page is the first thing I disable when I install a fresh eclipse... what makes it so important to you?

Comment: My application is built on top of Eclipse and welcome page is important .

Comment: I am not finding anything specific to this configuration, so may be a debug session of your application is in order to see what kind of `IntroModelRoot` is retrieved at the start of eclipse on SLED 64 vs. a Windows session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem Source. I was using incompatible version of **xulrunner**. Changing this to  version compatible with **eclipse** fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That error message comes directly form the [`SharedStyleManager`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/intro/impl/swt/SharedStyleManager.java.htm#ixzz0QcEoYNpS) class.

```
try {
    URL JavaDoc styleURL = new URL JavaDoc(style);
    InputStream JavaDoc is = styleURL.openStream();
    properties.load(is);
    is.close();
    context.path = new Path(style).removeLastSegments(1);
    String JavaDoc t = (String JavaDoc)properties.get("theme"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    if (t!=null && t.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) //$NON-NLS-1$
        context.inTheme = true;
} catch (Exception JavaDoc e) {
    Log.error("Could not load SWT style: " + style, e); //$NON-NLS-1$
}
```

Do you have the exception bundle within the "Could not load SWT style" exception? (in your Error view)

Comment: here are the details
Messgae: Could not load SWT style: content/shared.css


Exception Stack Trace:

java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: content/shared.css
 at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:567)
 at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
 at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.swt.SharedStyleManager.load(SharedStyleManager.java:66)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.swt.SharedStyleManager.<init>(SharedStyleManager.java:58)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.presentations.FormIntroPartImplementation.<init>(FormIntroPartImplementation.java:94)

Comment: at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.model.IntroPartPresentation.createPartControl(IntroPartPresentation.java:257)
 at org.eclipse.ui.intro.config.CustomizableIntroPart.createPartControl(CustomizableIntroPart.java:194)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewIntroAdapterPart.createPartControl(ViewIntroAdapterPart.java:98)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:371)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:230)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:594)

Comment: at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.showView(Perspective.java:2131)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyShowView(WorkbenchPage.java:1062)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$19.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3773)
 at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:3770)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:3746)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchIntroManager.createIntro(WorkbenchIntroManager.java:173)

Comment: The os string passed from the extension is "win32 mac linux"

Comment: The problem is reproducible only on SLED 11 64 bit machine.